# What is the result of relational operations on two pointers to different base class subobject

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    int a;
};
struct B{
    float b;
};
struct C:A,B{
    int c;
};

int main(){
  C* ptr = new C{};
  A* aptr = ptr;
  B* bptr = ptr;
  bool b = (void*)bptr > (void*)aptr;
  bool b2 = (void*)aptr > (void*)bptr;
  std::cout<< b<<std::endl;
  std::cout<< b2<<std::endl;
}
```

In this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/G3avEcfh1), both GCC and Clang say `bptr` is greater than `aptr`. However, [expr.rel] p4 says

> The result of comparing unequal pointers to objects71 is defined in terms of a partial order consistent with the following rules:
>
> > - If two pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to subobjects thereof, the pointer to the element with the higher subscript is required to compare greater.
> > - If two pointers point to different non-static data members of the same object, or to subobjects of such members, recursively, the pointer to the later declared member is required to compare greater provided neither member is a subobject of zero size and their class is not a union.
> > - **Otherwise, neither pointer is required to compare greater than the other**.

Obviously, in this case, the third bullet applies to this case. The result should be `false` for both `b` and `b2`. What's the reason Clang and GCC say `bptr` is greater than `aptr`?

Comment: Why should the result be `false`?  Why doesn't second bullet apply to this case?  Are `A` and `B` subjects of `C`?

Comment: "not required" is very different from "not allowed". Some of the rules are written for systems with segmented memory, where comparing pointers into different segments make little sense.

Comment: @Eljay The second bullet only applies to **non-static data members**. The base class subobject is not a non-static data member.

Comment: @Eljay However, `A` and `B` are not subobjects of **such members**. "Such members" refers to the **different non-static data members** of the same object.

Comment: Based on the wording of second bullet, I concur.  (I suspect the wording of second bullet accidentally omits the case of the object itself and its subobjects.)  In any case, it leaves third bullet:  why should the result be `false` for both `b` and `b2`?  That's not required by third bullet.

Comment: @BoP So, you meant "no required to compare greater than the other"  should be conveyed to that one pointer can compare greater than the other but **is not imposed by the standard**?

Comment: Have you ever worked with a computer with segmented memory architecture?  Have you ever worked with a computer with banked memory architecture?  C++ supports both of them.  (That is not an exhaustive list; there may be other memory architectures where third bullet is applicable.)

Comment: «every communist is an atheist» + «X is an atheist» does not mean that X is a communist. Similarly, if «`p` compares greater than `q`» requires `p > q` to produce `true`, and `(void*)bptr > (void*)aptr` is producing `true` does not mean that `bptr` compares greater than `aptr`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Oh, I see your point. You meant we cannot infer the condition from the result. `If P then Q` does not mean `Q => P`. I figure out a simple example: `int a = 0; int* ptr = &a; int * ptr2 = &a;`, `ptr == ptr2` is true. However, according to [expr.rel] p4, the results of `ptr > ptr2` and `ptr2 > ptr` are not required  by the standard, Right?

Comment: [expr.rel]/4 is about «compares greater» relation, the result of comparison expressions is defined in [expr.rel]/5

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes, [expr.rel] p4 defines the result of comparing **unequal** pointers.  The correct simplified should be: `int a; int b; int* aptr = &a; int* bptr= &b; ` then the results of `aptr > bptr` and `bptr > aptr` are not required by the standard.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer So, Please confirm the correct interpretation of the third bullet. Does "neither pointer is required to compare greater than the other" mean the document imposes no requirement on the result? In other words, one pointer **can** compare greater than the other, or less than the other, or can be other cases. They all obey the standard.

Comment: It measn https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.rel#5.sentence-3 apply

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously, in this case, the third bullet applies to this case

No, the second bullet applies. `a` and `b` are non-static data members of the same object (the `C` instance).

> If two pointers point to different non-static data members of the same object, or to subobjects of such members, recursively, the pointer to the later declared member is required to compare greater provided neither member is a subobject of zero size and their class is not a union.

And `struct C : A,B` makes `B` declared later than `A` so `bptr > aptr == true`.

Comment: No, the second bullet explicitly says it applies to **non-static data members** or the subobject of such members. A base class subobject is not a **non-static data member**.

Comment: @xmh0511 The `aptr` is pointing att the `a` in `A` and `bptr` is pointing `b` in `B`. `B` (and its `b`) are declared later than `A` (and its `a`). I updated the answer.

Comment: See [conv.ptr] p3. *A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a complete class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv B”, where B is a base class ([class.derived]) of D.* ... The result of the conversion is a pointer to **the base class subobject** of the derived class object. No conversion here make `aptr` and `bptr` points to the non-static data member, respectively.

Comment: @xmh0511 Do you agree that `&aptr->a` and `&bptr->b` have different addresses and that these addresses are `aptr` and `bptr`?

Comment: `aptr->a` and `bptr->b` are non-static data member of class `A` and class `B`, respectively. However, a base class subobject is not a non-static data member, hence the second bullet is not suitable for the case.

Comment: @xmh0511 Both `a` and `b` are non-static data members of `C`. `this->a` and `this->b` from within a `C` member function would be fine, right?

Comment: *Both a and b are non-static data members of C*. Agree on this point, since the non-static data members of the base classes are also members of the derived class. However, the pointer `aptr` and the pointer `bptr` **do not** points to the non-static data member anyway. They point to the base class subobjects according to the conversion.

Comment: @xmh0511 [data members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members): _"A pointer to an object of standard-layout class type can be `reinterpret_cast` to pointer to its first non-static non-bitfield data member (if it has non-static data members) "_ - so, I think you'll find they do.

Comment: In this case, no "reinterpret_cast" conversion is performed. Only the derived-to-base conversion applies the declaration of `aptr` and `bptr`.

Comment: @xmh0511 Sure - but the point is that they have the same address.

Comment: Even though they have the same address, they actually point to different objects. The bullet is defined for which object the pointer points.

Comment: @xmh0511 `B` is defined later than `A` so `b` is defined later than `a`. A pointer to `B` points at the same address as a pointer to the non-`static` data member `b` and a pointer to `A` points at the same address as a pointer to the non-`static` data member  `a`.  I don't see any room for anything else than `bptr > aptr == true`.

Comment: No, according to [expr.cast] p4, `static_cast<void*>(ptr)` is the interpreted conversion by the notation `(void*)ptr` here.

Comment: @xmh0511 What conversion is that? I'm talking about comparing `aptr` with `bptr` that points at the same addresses as `&ptr->a` and `&ptr->b`.

Comment: Once you'll learn the difference between addresses and pointer values and will stop generating cringe

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Care to elaborate? What I mean is that since `&ptr->b > &ptr->a == true` so is `bptr > aptr`, or `(void*) bptr == (void*) &ptr->b` if you will.

Comment: _Care to elaborate?_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73762139/what-is-the-result-of-relational-operations-on-two-pointers-to-different-base-cl/73762251?noredirect=1#comment130250697_73762251